# How to set to not print out DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.log for google log?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, google-cloud-logging

I connected with google log.When I started for spring boot,the program is died.Because Too many logs print out. This is my log and error.

```
[grpc-nio-worker-ELG-1-4] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.log - [id: 0x6413875c, L:/xxx:58478 - R:logging.googleapis.com/142.251.42.202:443] INBOUND HEADERS: streamId=207 headers=GrpcHttp2ResponseHeaders[grpc-status: 0, content-disposition: attachment] padding=0 endStream=true
[grpc-nio-worker-ELG-1-4] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.log - [id: 0x6413875c, L:/xxx:58478 - R:logging.googleapis.com/142.251.42.202:443] OUTBOUND HEADERS: streamId=459 headers=GrpcHttp2OutboundHeaders[:authority: logging.googleapis.com:443, :path: /google.logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2/WriteLogEntries, :method: POST, :scheme: https, content-type: application/grpc, te: trailers, user-agent: grpc-java-netty/1.39.0, x-goog-api-client: gl-java/11.0.10 gccl/2.3.2 gapic/2.3.2 gax/1.66.0 grpc/1.39.0, grpc-accept-encoding: gzip, authorization: Bearer ya29.c.b0AXv0zTNJXzltMy4mjSxLeBBi5FEjdutXjFapVXcbzZAkTR3NmGbQTCas6LsKA0N2OMAwlrH45Vo2TsxXA_gnhiIkOBUFoGpmltPxKln_vVYQcXsc6ogfViKv5RfSTFdFQF9vbvIpD5WMlYNBxeLVZjczD5zqQVYHYX9MyW9dcAF8U8B3MpYiOGam5gljwxEPevleZtRrdaMT9N1XwrQOQ4akSdZFyJU, grpc-timeout: 49999860u] streamDependency=0 weight=16 exclusive=false padding=0 endStream=false
[grpc-nio-worker-ELG-1-4] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.log - [id: 0x6413875c, L:/xxx:58478 - R:logging.googleapis.com/142.251.42.202:443] OUTBOUND DATA: streamId=261 padding=0 endStream=true length=1049 bytes=00000004140a2470726f6a656374732f64786d726f632f6c6f67732f6170706c69636174696f6e2e6c6f67121f0a076761655f61707012140a0a70726f6a6563...
[grpc-nio-worker-ELG-1-4] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.log - [id: 0x6413875c, L:/xxx:58478 - R:logging.googleapis.com/142.251.42.202:443] OUTBOUND DATA: streamId=459 padding=0 endStream=true length=1050 bytes=00000004150a2470726f6a656374732f64786d726f632f6c6f67732f6170706c69636174696f6e2e6c6f67121f0a076761655f61707012140a0a70726f6a6563...
[grpc-nio-worker-ELG-1-4] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.log - [id: 0x6413875c, L:/xxx:58478 - R:logging.googleapis.com/142.251.42.202:443] OUTBOUND DATA: streamId=457 padding=0 endStream=true length=1050 bytes=00000004150a2470726f6a656374732f64786d726f632f6c6f67732f6170706c69636174696f6e2e6c6f67121f0a076761655f61707012140a0a70726f6a6563...
[grpc-nio-worker-ELG-1-4] DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.log - [id: 0x6413875c, L:/xxx:58478 - R:logging.googleapis.com/142.251.42.202:443] OUTBOUND DATA: streamId=455 padding=0 endStream=true length=1050 bytes=00000004150a2470726f6a656374732f64786d726f632f6c6f67732f6170706c69636174696f6e2e6c6f67121f0a076761655f61707012140a0a70726f6a6563...
...
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: deadline exceeded after 49.999977764s. [remote_addr=logging.googleapis.com/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx]
```

I sow [google log document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/java).The google recommand to use logging.properties and use io.grpc and sun.net logging level is kept at INFO level

> it is recommended that io.grpc and sun.net logging level is kept at INFO level,
> as both these packages are used by Cloud internals and can result in verbose / initialization problems.
> io.grpc.netty.level=INFO
> sun.net.level=INFO

I added logging.properties and -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties.

```
io.grpc.netty.level=INFO
sun.net.level=INFO
```

But It didn't work, still print out too many logs.

**How to set to not print out "DEBUG io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyClientHandler.log"?** I am using logback.

This is my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <target>System.out</target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}:%-3relative][%thread] %-5level %logger{100}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="CLOUD" class="com.google.cloud.logging.logback.LoggingAppender">
        <log>application.log</log> 
        <resourceType>gae_app</resourceType> 
        <credentialsFile>myfile</credentialsFile>
        <enhancer>com.example.logging.logback.enhancers.ExampleEnhancer
        </enhancer> 
        <flushLevel>WARN</flushLevel> 
    </appender>

    <root level="debug"> <!-- ☆☆ If I use debug level, The program is died -->
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

pom.xml in relation to google log

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>24.1.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-logging-logback</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that through easy way. I only added this code in logback.xml.That is I changed log level of io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty to debug from info.

```
<logger name="io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty" level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="CLOUD" />
</logger>
```